# Bluetooth LE TX Power reading

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

How do i get a bluetooth device's TX power reading?

I have a bluetooth device, and some calibration software.

I'd like to understand if Tx is 4db or Tx is -40db what does it mean?

Comment: If you don't know what it means then why do you want to get it?

Comment: I want to be able to estimate the distance of the bluetooth device from my phone - I found a formula that would give me that, providing i have RSSI and TX power. I have RSSI, i can read that in the broadcast. But how do I get the power?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Tx power of a BLE device is usually made available in the Tx Power service 0x1804 and Tx Power Level Characteristic 0x2A07. Take a look at [this page](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.tx_power.xml) as it shows how the Tx Power Level is encapsulated in the Tx Power service. So, from your Android code you should scan for available services, and once you find the 0x1804 read the value of the 0x2A07 characteristic. However, this is not compulsory, and the Tx Power Level can be made available under a custom service or even through BLE adverts, depending on the bluetooth device.

Note that the Tx power is measured in dBm (dB is too high for Bluetooth devices). Both 4dBm and -40dBm are valid Tx power levels, but 4dBm is much more likely as -40dBm is too low would make it very difficult for devices to read the data of the BLE device.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: I want to be able to "discover" the device, only if i am within say 5-10 meters away from the device. The bluetooth chip i got, says that it is discoverable for up to 45 meters (which is too much for me, because i want to filter only for devices that are really nearby). So if i make the dBm be closer to 4 that will help me achieve my goal ?

Comment: No, if you make the dBm to 4 you will still be able to discover the device from within 45 meters. If you change it to -40 dBm then this is more likely, but even then that wont be very precise. In the end you will have to keep decreasing the Tx Power and do some experimentation before determining the optimal Tx Power for your goal.

Comment: "dB is too high" -> dB is not a unit of power, were you thinking of dBW?

Comment: @Oil Charlesworth. Yes this is what I meant.